# Order in a Join is really a big trouble?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlperformance

I made this query

```
select L.some_variable, C.id from l_table L
left join c_table C using (some_variable)
where C.id is null
```

Then looked to an more complete version of the query above

```
select L.*, C.* from l_table L
left join c_table C using (some_variable)
where C.id is null
order by L.some_variable
```

The second took 8x the time.  I'm sure that L. *, C. * wasn't the 'guilty'.  The *some_variable* is a string field.  But ordering this cannot be an 20 min operation.  What is the source of so many difference?

*some_variable* is not an index too, but this would impact on both operations, or ordering needs some sort of indexing to perform well in joins?

Comment: Show `explain analyze` for both please.

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: I think it's slowed down by the "order by",which has to sort your result, possibly using a filesort.

Comment: Unless the data can be retrieved in the required order with an index, the `order by` will cause a sort. It may only be sorting a string field (and an internal row pointer) but it has to apply the order to all the result rows. So, the size of the ordered column, the number and size of the columns being selected, and the number of rows are all important factors. As CraigRinger stated, you need an explain to determine what is happening.

Comment: Also, when trying to understand something, only change one thing at a time. Here you are adding all columns and the order by. Then you say "I'm sure that L*, C.* wasn't the 'guilty'" - but did you try it both ways?

Answer (score 0):

If this is your query:

```
select L.*, C.*
from l_table L left join
     c_table C
     using (some_variable)
where C.id is null
order by L.some_variable;
```

I would be inclined to write it as:

```
select l.*
from l_table l
where not exists (select 1 from c_table c where () )
order by l.some_variable;
```

The columns from `table_c` seem superfluous in the `select` since they would presumably be `NULL`.

For this query, an index on `l_table(l.some_variable, <variables in where>)` might be able to prevent the sort that takes so much time.